# getting wp posts by tags similar to arg - wp db query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, search, tags

I use below code for getting posts by a word similar tag but not working

```
$query = "
         SELECT *
         FROM   $wpdb->posts ,  $wpdb->terms , $wpdb->term_relationships
         WHERE  $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '$search_query%'
         AND    $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
         AND    $wpdb->term_relationship.object_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
         ORDER BY   $wpdb->posts.post_title";


     $search_songs = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        $new_query = new WP_Query( $search_songs );
        $search_songs_posts = $new_query->posts;
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have seen your first query looks fine.

```
$query_byTag="
        SELECT wp_posts.ID
        FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_terms
        WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_terms.name LIKE '".$search_query."%'";
    $search_songs = $wpdb->get_results($query_byTag);
```

This query returns all posts IDs as an array of object.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 60
        )

)
```

Now you need to pass `$search_songs` array of object `WP_Query($search_songs)` as:

```
$new_query = new WP_Query( $search_songs );
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($search_songs);//returns all posts with query and others data
 echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to get only posts then you can get it as:

```
echo '<pre>';
     print_r($search_songs->posts);//returns all posts 
     echo '</pre>';
```

[For more details](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/how-to-query-posts-by-category-and-tag)

Comment: i don't understand, what's problem ? why need loop and where exactly ?

Comment: do one thing `print_r($search_songs)`.

Comment: i know, but don't return any things

Comment: @ebeliejinfren, I have updated my answer and also tested it, now It's working.